# pass true or false from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I need to use conditional statement in my controller which I should pass it from the model.

Model

```
function checking() {

   ....
   ....
   ....

   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
     if (one field is not empty) {
          $statement == true
     }
     else {
          $statement == false
     }

}
```

Controller

```
   $data['records'] = $this->the_model->checking();       
   ...
   if($statement == true) {
       something will be generate here;      
   }     

   else if ($statement == false) {
       something else be generate here;      
   }     
   else {
       nothing;      
   }
```

One thing is I don't want to pass it as array in looping as the result I got from my sql query is in looping. I just want to get SIGNLE info if it is `false` or `true`. It may look like cookie or session (which is impossible to get it from model) or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Model

```
function checking() {

   ....
   ....
   ....

   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
     if (one field is not empty) {
          $statement == true
     }
     else {
          $statement == false
     }

   //return the value of statement
   return $statement;

}
```

In Controller

```
$statement = $this->the_model->checking();

if($statement == true) {
       something will be generate here;      
   }     

   else if ($statement == false) {
       something else be generate here;      
   }     
   else {
       nothing;      
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function in model that would return boolean... For example

```
 public function getBooleanValue(){
    //based on your checks return either true or false;
 }
```

on the controller end:

```
 $statement= $this->the_model->getBooleanValue();
```

Use this $statement in the code as boolean

Comment: can you please show me how to slip it (`getBooleanValue()`) in my `function checking()`

Comment: @iyal just return $statement before closing the function }  and change $data['records'] = $this->the_model->checking();   to $statement =$this->the_model->checking();

Comment: I am still not sure what you say, can you please draw it completely in the answer box, please..